# Displays editText value sharedpreference save

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, savestate

I have 3 EditText. When i enter some text or some numbers then click save button it goes to another Activity. Again come back on editText, the values are gone and set to android:text="value". I need to display the values after typing in editText box.

code:

```
et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pieces);

        et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.portions);

        et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ml);

        save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit_data);

save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("text1",pieces.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("text2",portions.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("text3",ml.getText().toString());

                editor.commit();



            String oneedit= preferences .getString("text1", "");
            String  twoedit= preferences .getString("text2", "" );
            String  thirdedit= preferences .getString("text3", "" );


            pieces.setText(oneedit);
            portions.setText(twoedit);
            ml.setText(thirdedit);

            /*
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("text1",pieces.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("text2",portions.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("text3",ml.getText().toString());

            editor.commit();


                Intent intent=new Intent(Activity.this,Activity1.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

    });
```

If i use below code, it loads the saved values:

```
edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

                //edittext.setText(sharedpreference.getString(KEYNAME, "No value Stored"));

                et.setText(preferences.getString("text1", " "));
                et1.setText(preferences.getString("text2", " "));
                et2.setText(preferences.getString("text3", " "));

            }


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this  this line we call on `create method` and use whole activity

```
  SharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
```

save.setOnClickListener()

```
   save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SharedPreferences .edit();
            editor.putString("text1",et.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("text2",e1t.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("text3",et2.getText().toString());

            editor.commit();

              et.setText("");
         et1.setText("");
         et2.setText("");  
       }
});
```

this is onClick method

```
     edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub               

         String oneedit= SharedPreferences .getString("text1", null);
         String twoedit= SharedPreferences .getString("text2", null );
         String threeedit= SharedPreferences .getString("text3", null );

         et.setText(oneedit);
         et1.setText(twoedit);
         et2.setText(threeedit);     

        }
    });
```

Comment: what can i use for et2?

Comment: just add what ever we want

Comment: what is your answer? Im confusing. why save.setOnClickListerner() and onClick means?

Comment: see my edited question with your answer. But it's not working

Comment: No. EditText values are gone after click save button.

Comment: when i enter some text inside edittext after hitting save button i display another activity. Then i come back to edittext value screen, the edittext values are set to default. It won't displays what i entered before

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37709/discussion-between-nagarjunareddy-and-user2674668)

Comment: I use this answer and i set the value perfectly. I think @user2674668 is can't set preference perfectly Other wise this answer is Right 
Thank you :) #@NagarjunaReddy